# General output does not return anything

Tags: java, output, jcreator

I'm trying to use Stringtokenizer to read off several lines in a file and display relevant info using a `while` loop (for a school project), but the general output in JCreator seems to not return anything despite any changes I make.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class EmployeePayWeek10

{
  //file input variables
  private static FileInputStream inFile;
  private static InputStreamReader inReader;
  private static BufferedReader reader;

  //StringTokenizer variable
  private static StringTokenizer stringTkn;

  //Data variables
  private static String firstName, lastName, line;
  private static double hourlyWage;
  private static double hoursMon, hoursTue, hoursWed, hoursThu, hoursFri;
  private static double ovtMon, ovtTue, ovtWed, ovtThu, ovtFri;
  private static double ovtHoursWorked, hoursWorked, effectiveWage, roundedWage;
  private static double weeklyWage;

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException

  {

    startFile();
    acquireValues();
    inFile.close();


  }
    //Initializing the file
    public static void startFile() throws IOException

    {

      inFile = new FileInputStream ("C:\\!!VHSJava\\!!VHSAPCSData\\VHSP35week10data.txt");
      inReader = new InputStreamReader(inFile);
      reader = new BufferedReader(inReader);

    }
    //Acquiring data values from the .txt file
    public static void acquireValues() throws IOException

    {

     line = reader.readLine();

     while(line != null);
     {

     //Separating the series of words into tokens
     stringTkn = new StringTokenizer(line);

     //Name variables
     firstName = stringTkn.nextToken();
     lastName = stringTkn.nextToken();

     //Wage variables, defined in order of the notepad file
     hourlyWage = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     hoursMon = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     ovtMon = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     hoursTue = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     ovtTue = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     hoursWed = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     ovtWed = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     hoursThu = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     ovtThu = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     hoursFri = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());
     ovtFri = Double.parseDouble(stringTkn.nextToken());

     calcWage();
     returnWage();


    line = reader.readLine();

    }
    }

    //Weekly wage is calculated and rounded to two decimal places. (At most)

    public static void calcWage() throws IOException
    {

        hoursWorked = (hoursMon + hoursTue + hoursWed + hoursThu + hoursFri);
        ovtHoursWorked = (ovtMon + ovtTue + ovtWed + ovtThu + ovtFri);
        effectiveWage = (hoursWorked * hourlyWage) + (1.5 * ovtHoursWorked * hourlyWage);
        roundedWage = (double)Math.round(effectiveWage * 100) / (100);

    }

    //Calculated weekly wage is returned alongside name of employee.

    public static void returnWage() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println(firstName + lastName + "Weekly Wage: " + roundedWage);
    }
} //End of class
```

I've tried other programs to see if the output is messed up due to something wrong with Java, but other files work fine. Is there anything here that could possibly be interfering with the output being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `acquireValues()` method:

```
while(line != null);
```

You have a `;` which should not be there. Remove it.

Comment: That actually fixed all of it. Thanks!